# How to send and receive data in Android Programming using bluetooth without pairing?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I am new to Android programming, and have java concept, I want to know that how can I send and receive data using bluetooth without pairing or any password (Only if both device has my app installed), 
any suggestion?

Comment: Sockets can skip the BT portion and go direct via Wifi (IP). It might be easier than navigating the searching + pairing steps of BT.

Comment: I have the same problem, I am trying to recive information from range finder by bluetooth without pairing the devices ( and I am 100% sure that it is possible ). Have You get any solution ?

Comment: @SalutAmigo, This question I asked in 2011, and now it's 2017. It was not possible at that time due to security set by Android. I have no idea, how library behaving now. So, read their official documentation about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it's impossible to send *or* receive data over RFCOMM sockets without pairing.  I've tried this extensively with an application that I'm developing.  My results are:

- If the two devices are paired and discoverable, bi-directional communication is possible
- If the two devices are paired, but the "server" device (the one the android device is trying to connect to) is set to be *not* discoverable, then bi-directional communication is still possible
- If the two devices are not paired, but the "server" device *is* discoverable, then a pairing request is still required before bi-directional communication is possible.  This means that RFCOMM *client* sockets (i.e., those from Android) require the devices to be paired.  This was tested on a Samsung Captivate running Android 2.2.  I find this very strange, as I can understand requiring pairing before allowing RFCOMM server sockets, but requiring pairing for *client* sockets is a bit stringent.

As @ethrbunny mentioned you can also just use WiFi, setup parallel server/client threads on each device, and send whatever you want.  To discover services on a local network you can optionally use zeroconf.

Answer (score 1):

I got the the following from [this Google groups post by Kristopher Micinski](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/69d7810f6ef9bb7d#msg_d114dbd1b5e86945).
Hope it helps.

> I believe the key to getting this to work is in the `mUuid` list.
>
> Take a close look at what this is doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Connection.MAX_SUPPORTED && myBSock == null; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3 && myBSock == null; j++) {
        myBSock = getConnectedSocket(myBtServer, mUuid.get(i));
        if (myBSock == null) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "InterruptedException in connect", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> What this code does is looks to connect to the device, but how does it
>   do so? It tries the socket multiple times, using multiple UUIDs for
>   the session.
>
> In essence it means that we can use UUID only *once*. So instead this
>   application implements using seven UUIDs, then the server listens and
>   accepts each UUID on the server side, this is what is done with the
>   following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Connection.MAX_SUPPORTED && maxConnections > 0; i++) {
    BluetoothServerSocket myServerSocket = mBtAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(srcApp, mUuid.get(i));
    BluetoothSocket myBSock = myServerSocket.accept();
    myServerSocket.close(); // Close the socket now that the
    // connection has been made.

    String address = myBSock.getRemoteDevice().getAddress();

    mBtSockets.put(address, myBSock);
    mBtDeviceAddresses.add(address);
    Thread mBtStreamWatcherThread = new Thread(new BtStreamWatcher(address));
    mBtStreamWatcherThread.start();
    mBtStreamWatcherThreads.put(address, mBtStreamWatcherThread);
    maxConnections = maxConnections - 1;
    if (mCallback != null) {
        mCallback.incomingConnection(address);
    }
}
```

> Now, on the client side of things what is done? The client does not
>   know how many active connections the server currently has.
>
> If we have some agreed upon order that the clients must use we can
>   simply use this, however, in our case, we simply just try *each UUID*
>   in sequence until we "find the right one."
>
> **Short version:**   -- Use multiple UUIDs, you can only use one at once. So define seven (max for piconet usage) and try each one until
>   you find the right one.

Comment: but dear I want to send and receive both, like I send one string to Android then that android will also send me ,,,,, means both client and server be a device, so what do u say?

Comment: For what you're (apparently) trying to do it won't matter who is client/server once they are connected. They will just swap messages. Both processes will have some blocking process on 'socket->read' that traps characters until a full message is rec'd. Then deal with the message and respond.