# Is it possible to send a message from one android mobile to another android mobile using bluetooth or wifi with out pairing?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, android-wifi

Presently I am doing my work in the android field. I am trying to develop an application to send a message from my bluetooth/wi-fi enabled mobile to other bluetooth/wi-fi enabled mobiles without pairing.

Is it possible to send message to another mobile in my blueooth or wi-fi range without pairing? If it possible how can I send the message to another mobile with out pairing?

Answer (score 2):

If your talking about SMS this does not apply.

For Wifi have a look at this project http://code.google.com/p/remotedroid/.

For Bluetooth this thread explains how to archive what your looking for.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

To send data over to Bluetooth device all you need is the Mac address of that device.
Read the Bluetooth tutorial, its very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For sending Message (SMS,MMS), I don't think so, Without pairing how could you know the device Id, to which you want to send a message, And if you don't pair the devices then how they communicated to each other,

**EDIT:** For bluetooth As per my knowledge it's impossible to send or receive data over RFCOMM sockets without pairing.

And for WiFi , setup parallel server/client threads on each device, and send whatever you want. To discover services on a local network you can optionally use zeroconf.

Look at these links,

[Bluetooth pairing without user confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885438/bluetooth-pairing-without-user-confirmation)

[Bluetooth SPP between Android and other device, UUID and PIN questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263144/bluetooth-spp-between-android-and-other-device-uuid-and-pin-questions)

[How to send and receive data in Android Programming using bluetooth without pairing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494006/how-to-send-and-receive-data-in-android-programming-using-bluetooth-without-pair)

Comment: hello... thanks for u r reply...... actually my application is when i android mobile detects the all the mobiles with in a range then it sends a message to all the detected mobiles. is it possible???

Answer (score 0):

Shortly and sweetly, No.. You cant send messages to other mobiles without some kind of authentication.