# Where data can be buffered on rfcomm connection?

Tags: c, bluetooth, buffer, rfcomm

i'm trying to pass data between two bluetooth devices, when both connected to two different computers. 
After having `hci` device in each of the computers, i'm using `rfcomm` to pass information between the two.

I'm trying to pass 10MB of random data just to check the ability of the system.
On the beginning everything seems to work fine. After a few seconds, it looks like there is a delay between the sender and the receiver, when sometimes data stopps to arrive, and then a "massive" amount of data is suddenly arriving the receiver.

Exactly like some buffer is keeping all the data. As long i keep sending data 
the delay is getting longer.
I'm trying to figure out where in the chain such buffer can be, or how to 
solve this buffering.

Many Thanks :)

Comment: You can see a simple using rfcomm bluetooth socket between two blue bluetooth device in My answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046480/7508077

Comment: Server side code have a buffer to save receiving messages. consider second line inside `main()` we have  `char buf[1024] = { 0 };` and when it receive message save it on buffer: `bytes_read = read(client, buf, sizeof(buf));
`